# What is the right place for Product Image

Tags: forms, commerce

We can take image of product through Product Type or Product Display content type, I just want to know what is the right place for product images fields ?

Answer (score 2):

It is related to want you want, if you want have a product display with some variation that each variation  different with each other ( different image) it is better put product image field in product , but if all product variation has equal image (or you have not product display  with multi variation product ) it is better put image field in product display content type .

I hope this can helped you.